# How to add nonclustered indexes in Entity Framework db-first project?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table in SQL Server which includes custom nonclustered indexes for some columns. And I have also a project with below versions.

- .Net Framework 4.6.2
- Entity Framework 6.4.4

I added an entity data model to project based on my existing database (using a database-first approach).

Although a `SELECT` query returns quickly in database, the same query gets a timeout error in the project. And I thought that EF couldn't add
column indexes to the project. I searched index names in the project,
but there isn't any code about indexes in the project.

So, how can I add indexes to my database-first model?

Comment: The indexes aren't added to **EF** - if anything, they would be added in the **SQL Server** database..... From EF, you'd have to use migrations to do something like this (change/modify the structure of the database)

Comment: You could just add a migration and execute arbitrary SQL in the migration, including a "create index...".

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking, mainly because you seem to have a wrong perception of what indexes are and where they play a role. Stick to the problem: differences in performance. Are you executing *exactly* the same SQL query as EF does?

Comment: `Database first` means you create the database first, including any indexes. `there isn't any code about indexes in the project.` there wouldn't be. You don't write any index-specific code in your SQL query after all.

Comment: `the same query gets a timeout error in the project` what does your code do? How much data is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how can I add indexes to my database-first model?

"database-first" means that you apply design changes to the *database first*, and then apply any changes to the EF model second.

So you just create the indexes in SQL Server using [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-sql-database-by-using-a-designer?view=vs-2022) or [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15), and since EF model doesn't need to  change when you add an index, you're done.